# VBA code where sheet 1 cell follows background color of sheet 2 cell and cell value does not matter

Tags: excel

While there are a lot of similar questions to my own, I have been unable to find an answer based on my specific need. FYI - learning this stuff on my own.

Part 1:

I have set up conditional formatting on several cells between sheets 2-10 to change colors as they approach a due date.  At 7 days it changes green, 3 days changes orange and the day of changes red and maintains red until I go in and move the date further out.

I would like cell(s) on sheet 1 to mirror the color changes of cells or groups of cells on a different sheet despite what value is in the cell. Example: Sheet two cells N16 and N17 have due dates 01/15/19 and will turn colors as mentioned above.  I would like cell A5 on sheet 1 to follow the color changes of N16 and N17 on sheet two.

Comment: `Part 1` and `Part 2` are too different to be in the same question. We help with specific questions. Not the entirety of peoples projects.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  An example of your data and expected outcome would assist us in assisting you. Also, it is expected that you try something first and post that along with what it doesn't do that you need. Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with creating a module and a macro, if that is so, insert a button with that macro or place it under worksheet activate:

```
IF THISWORKBOOK.SHEETS("sheet1").range("N16").Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
THEN
THISWORKBOOK.SHEETS("sheet2").range("a5").Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
```